# Proving a markov chain is recurrent iff harmonic function has infinite limit:

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

Let $p_0=1, 0<p_n<1$ a sequence of probabilities.

define: $[A_{i,j}]_{i,j\in\mathbb N_0}$, $A_{0,0}=1$ , $A_{i,i-1}=1-p_i$ ,$A_{i,i+1}=p_i$

definition: $h:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb R$ will be called harmonic at $n$ if $h_n=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N_0}[(A_{n,k})\cdot h_k]$.

I have already proven that $h$, harmonic on all $\mathbb N$ [without $0$] exists, and unique if $h_0,h_1$ are given. and dependant only on $p_1;\dots;p_{n-1}$

**Now I need to prove that the chain is recurrent iff  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}h_n=\infty $.**

Definition: a markov chain will be called recurrent at $m$ if starting at $X_n=m$: $P(min\{k\geq 1,X_{n+k}=m\})=1$ [the probability of returning to $m$ after arriving at $m$ in **finite time** is $1$.

I think I should be using Doob's Optional Stopping Time Theorem, but I have no idea how. Please Help.

Comment: Do you perhaps intend that $A_{i,i-1}=p_i$?

Comment: corrected, ty @JohnDawkins

Comment: Isn't $h_n=1$ (constant function) harmonic? Also, if $h$ is harmonic then so is $2h$, so uniqueness seems to fail without further conditions.

Comment: @JohnDawkins $h$ is a function from $\mathbb N_0$ to $\mathbb R$
$h_n = h(n)$ cause a function over the natural numbers is nothing but a sequence.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I have already proven uniqueness.

Comment: I think your notation in the equation $h_n = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}_0} [A_{nj} h_j]$ needs work.  The summation is over $k$, yet there are no $k$ indices inside the sum.  Also, what is $\mathbb{N}_0$?  The expression $P[\min[m \geq 1, X_m=n]]=1$ is also something I cannot interpret.

Comment: @Michael ty, updated the question.

Comment: @Michael $\mathbb N_0=\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$

Comment: So then it should be $h:\mathbb{N}_0\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ I presume, else we get for $k=1$ that $h_1=A_{10}h_0+...$ and so we need $h_0$ defined. As John Dawkins points out, $h_n=1$ for all $n$ is a solution (regardless of recurrence). And $h_n=0$ for all $n$ is another solution.

Comment: @Michael , no that's the point harmonic function on all $\mathbb N_0$ are constant, i have proven that. This function is harmonic only on $\mathbb N$. no mistake here. $h_2 =p_1^-1$ for example, cause $h_1=(1-p_1)h_0+p_1h_2$ .

Comment: I cannot understand your responses, they seem disconnected from the (clear) comments others have given you. [Example: If $h_0$ is not defined, then you cannot use it in an equation.]

Comment: I suspect you are really trying to prove the following (which is a provable theorem): Let $X(t)$ be an irreducible discrete time Markov chain with infinite state space $S=\{0,1,2,...\}$ and transition probabilities $(P_{ij})$. Suppose there exists a function $h:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} h_n = \infty$ and $h_n \geq \sum_{j\in S} P_{nj}h_j$ for all $n \in S$.  Then all states of $X(t)$ are recurrent. [You can assume without loss of generality that the $h$ function is nonnegative.]

Comment: $h_0=0, h_1=1$ and they define one unique harmonic function on $\mathbb N$

Comment: (If you care): [I am assuming $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$]  (i) If you define $h:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ then $h_0$ is not defined.  You would need to make it $h:\mathbb{N}_0\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. (ii) You can only take probabilities of events.  For example, it does not make sense to take probabilities of a random variable.  Is the object $\min\{k\geq 1, X_{n+k}=m\}$ an event or a random variable? Perhaps you really mean that $K_m$ is the random first time until we get back to state $m$, given we start there, and you want to consider $P[K_m<\infty]$?

Comment: @Michael o.k I accept ur note on defining 1st time of returning. still have no clue of how to answer

Comment: @Michael the function $h:\mathbb N_0 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $h_0=0, h_1=1$  from this, by using harmonic on $\mathbb N$ definition you have that there is only one way to define it. I have proven that already.

Comment: Assume $X(0)=0$ with prob 1, and define $M(t) = h_{X(t)}$.  Show a super-martigale (or martingale, if you prefer) property on $M(t)$.

Comment: I did that, it is a martingale.  $E(h_{X_n})=E(h_{X_1})$ for all n, now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h$ be the (non-negative) harmonic function with $h(0)=0$ and $h(1)=1$.
Start the Markov chain in state $1$, and consider the martingale $h(X_n)$. Let $T_k$ be the first hitting time of state $k$. Then by optional stopping 
$$
1=E[h(X_0)]\ge E[h(X_{T_0\wedge T_N})]=h(N)\cdot P[T_N<T_0],
$$
where $N\in\Bbb N$ is large. From this it is clear that if $\lim_Nh(N)=\infty$ then $P[T_0=\infty]=\lim_NP[T_N<T_0]=0$, and the chain is recurrent. Conversely, if $\lim_Nh(N)<\infty$ then $h$ is bounded, as is the martingale $h(X_n)$, so the inequality in the above display is an equality. Letting $N\to\infty$ you see that $P[T_0=\infty]=\lim_NP[T_N<T_0]>0$, and the chain cannot be recurrent.

Comment: I'll verify it tomorrow, if everything is o.k you'll get the bounty. @John Dawkins